# How to allow user to switch default local language?

Tags: java, android

In the area I live in, English is the official language, and all apps downloaded from the play store in Zambia are in English. In my app I have included a string resource file for a traditional language spoken in my area. How can I allow the user to switch from the res/values/strings to res/values/string_languagex, in an onClick method?

Comment: Am not sure as to why my question has been down voted. It is if relevance

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the phone's language from the onClick and it will switch to the needed string resources on it's own

Comment: @ Mahmoud Omara the  languages in my area are not known by phone systems